# Fastest way to check existence of DirectoryEntry

Tags: .net, directoryservices

I use the code below to check if a directory object exists but it is very slow when getting the Guid property (actually any property) - like 20 seconds slow.
path is a full LDAP:://xxxxxxxx path to a directory object.
Is there a better way to do this?

```
            using (DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(path, username, password)) {
                string s = de.Guid.ToString();
            }
```

Comment: You'd have to post your use-case. LDAP is slow so you really want to keep calls to a minimum.

Comment: It's an app that does some functions against AD. When the user chooses a particular path to use then I want to check that he has rights to the path before going further in the app...at the moment it is taking ages to get past that simple check.